# SQL Server rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My query is:

```
SELECT vendor.id, insurances.id AS ins_id, vendor_insurances.expiry_date
FROM vendor
INNER JOIN vendor_insurances
ON vendor.id=vendor_insurances.vendor_id
```

and the output:

```
id    ins_id    expiry_date
================================
28    1         2006-01-01
28    11        2008-01-01
```

I want to convert it to:

```
id    1            11
======================================
28    2006-01-01   2008-01-01
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and do something similar to this:

Static Pivot - for just a few number of columns that you will pivot

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT v.id
    , vi.id AS ins_id
    , vi.expiry_date
  FROM vendor v
  INNER JOIN vendor_insurances vi
    ON v.id=vi.vendorId
) x
PIVOT
(
   MIN(expiry_date)
    FOR ins_id IN ([1], [11])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31fca/3) for Working Demo

Or you can use a Dynamic Pivot if you have a lot of items to PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(vi.id) 
                  FROM vendor v
                  INNER JOIN vendor_insurances vi
                    ON v.id=vi.vendorId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT v.id
                    , vi.id AS ins_id
                    , vi.expiry_date
                FROM vendor v
                INNER JOIN vendor_insurances vi
                    ON v.id=vi.vendorId
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MIN(expiry_date)
                for ins_id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both will give you the same results.